# Proving ¬ (A ∧ B) → (A → ¬ B) in Lean

Tags: proof, theorem-proving, negation, lean

I"m trying to prove ¬ (A ∧ B) → (A → ¬ B) with the Lean theorem prover. I've set it up like so.

```
example : ¬ (A ∧ B) → (A → ¬ B) :=
assume h1: ¬ (A ∧ B),
assume h2: A,
show ¬ B, from sorry
```

I've tried using and.left and and.right for h1 but these do not work when the conjunction is negated. I am unable to find any examples that prove implication like this starting from a negation. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`¬ B` is defined to be `B -> false` so you could start with

```hs
example (A B : Prop): ¬ (A ∧ B) → (A → ¬ B) :=
assume h1: ¬ (A ∧ B),
assume h2: A,
assume h3: B,
show false, from sorry
```